# internet site Java Applet with firebird database

Tags: java, applet

i have some project to make for mys self, but i can not resolve a puzzle :)
for example i have such a code, but it is nor working on my website

it throws: `NoClassDefFoundError`

1. I create file  .java and link it with database(?)

   ```
   package firebird;

   import java.sql.*;

   public class Firebird {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

       String pathToDatabase;
       String userName;
       String password;
       String sql;

       sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE";
       password = "masterkey";
       userName = "sysdba";
       pathToDatabase = "C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_5/examples/empbuild/EMPLOYEE.FDB";

   try {
       Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
       } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
         System.out.println(cnfe.toString());  
         System.out.println("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver not found"); 
       }
   // Retrieve a connection.
   try {
       Statement stmt = null;
       ResultSet rst = null;
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
       "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:" + pathToDatabase, userName, password);
   try {
     stmt = conn.createStatement();
     rst = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
     int columnCount = rst.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
     int recordIndex = 0;
    while(rst.next()) {
     recordIndex++;
     System.out.println("Record: " + recordIndex);
       for (int i=1;i<=columnCount;i++) {
        System.out.print(rst.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
        System.out.print(": ");
        System.out.println(rst.getString(i));
       }
    }
   } finally {
   // close the database resources immediately, rather than waiting
   // for the finalizer to kick in later
     if (rst != null) { rst.close(); }
     if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
     conn.close();
   }
   } catch(SQLException se) {
     System.out.println(se.toString());
   }
   }        

   }
   ```
2. I compile code with console and get .class file
3. I create a .html file with following code:

   ```
   <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Java_DB</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    Svetainė parašyta su java ir joje duombazė <BR><BR>

    <applet code="Firebird.class" width="1000" height ="500">

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
   ```

Comment: Are you using an IDE? It depends on how you are running the application. You can debug it by following this - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 1):

You should add `archive` to your `applet tag` like that. If you have not Firebird.jar you should create it.

```
<applet 
    code="firebird/Firebird" 
    archive="Firebird.jar" 
    width=1000
    height=500>
</applet>
```

Comment: You have also added `</applet>` without comment.  Well, for HTML validity (up to 3.2, for the applet element), explicitly close the applet element, as seen in this answer.  Note that `code="Firebird.class"` should be `code="Firebird"`  - The Fully Qualified Name rather than the file/resource name.

Comment: Firstly i don't have an anchive file
secondly i still have an  NoClassDefFoundError
"Firebirb (wrong name: firebird/Firebird)

Comment: ok i created an archive called fire.jar
but when i try it to launch i get an error "A Java exception has occured" :(